# Is it possible for type II civ to resuscitate dying star?

Tags: technology, stars, kardashev-scale

I suppose there is sufficient time for us to achieve type 2 civ status on the Kardashev scale, that means we cannibalise the Sun! Joke aside would such a civilization level be sufficient to revert a white dwarf into a red giant and finally restore back the Sun to its main sequence stage? I know resources is scarce within the solar system but please look beyond the heliosphere and no FTL.

Comment: the main problem you will have is that the red giant, blows out it's outer layers into your solar system in the process of becoming a white dwarf... before you get to try and resuscitate your star, you need to survive this onslaught...

Comment: @Chris J: thanks for the advice, I'm sure type II allow human to migrate further out to maybe proxima centauri.

Answer (score 5):

Certainly.

## Stellar husbandry

That is one of the uses of [star lifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_lifting#Stellar_husbandry).

But you would **not revert a white dwarf**, anymore than you unburn coal. You start while it’s still in the main sequence, and you make the fuel last orders of magnitude longer, don’t waste power lighting up empty space, use it *all* by stirring it up, and don’t throw large quantities away as a red giant.

## Necro-star

In the novella *Palimpsest*, Charles Stross describes creating a “necro-star” to make the same amount of raw material last orders of magnitude longer.  Rather than fusion, the material is fed into a black hole at a measured rate.

You could use a white dwarf as source material in that scenario.

Comment: You mean to alter the ratio between inward and outward pressure to halt the dying process, so no colossal Benjamin button?

Comment: Read second paragraph [at link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_lifting#Stellar_husbandry).